# Using cbind on an arbitrarily long list of objects

Tags: r, join, statistics, bind, do.call

I would like to find a way to create a data.frame by using `cbind()` to join together many separate objects. For example, if A, B, C & D are all vectors of equal length, one can create `data.frame` ABCD with

```
ABCD <- cbind(A,B,C,D)
```

However, when the number of objects to be combined gets large, it becomes tedious to type out all of their names. Furthermore, Is there a way to call `cbind()` on a vector of object names, e.g.

```
objs <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
ABCD <- cbind(objs)
```

or on a list containing all the objects to be combined, e.g.

```
obj.list <- list(A,B,C,D)
ABCD <- cbind(obj.list)
```

Currently, the only workaround I can think of is to use `paste()`, `cat()`, `write.table()`, and `source()` to construct the arguments to `cbind()`, write it as a script and source it. This seems like a very nasty kludge. Also, I have looked into `do.call()` but can't seem to find a way to accomplish what I want with it.

Comment: `Reduce(cbind, obj.list)` could also be used in addition to the answer by @prasad-chalasani.

Answer (score 38):

The `do.call` function is very useful here:

```
A <- 1:10
B <- 11:20
C <- 20:11

> do.call(cbind, list(A,B,C))
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1   11   20
 [2,]    2   12   19
 [3,]    3   13   18
 [4,]    4   14   17
 [5,]    5   15   16
 [6,]    6   16   15
 [7,]    7   17   14
 [8,]    8   18   13
 [9,]    9   19   12
[10,]   10   20   11
```

Comment: This gets extremely inefficient as the data frame grows in size

Answer (score 9):

First you need to `get` the objects you want and store them together as a list; if you can construct their names as strings, you use the `get` function.  Here I create two variables, `A` and `B`:

```
> A <- 1:4
> B <- rep(LETTERS[1:2],2)
```

I then construct a character vector containing their names (stored as `ns`) and `get` these variables using `lapply`.  I then set the names of the list to be the same as their original names.

```
> (ns <- LETTERS[1:2])
[1] "A" "B"
> obj.list <- lapply(ns, get)
> names(obj.list) <- ns
> obj.list
$A
[1] 1 2 3 4

$B
[1] "A" "B" "A" "B"
```

Then you can use `do.call`; the first argument is the function you want and the second is a list with the arguments you want to pass to it.

```
> do.call(cbind, obj.list)
     A   B  
[1,] "1" "A"
[2,] "2" "B"
[3,] "3" "A"
[4,] "4" "B"
```

However, as aL3xa correctly notes, this makes a matrix, not a data frame, which may not be what you want if the variables are different classes; here my `A` has been coerced to a character vector instead of a numeric vector.  To make a data frame from a list, you just call `data.frame` on it; then the classes of the variables are retained.

```
> (AB <- data.frame(obj.list))
  A B
1 1 A
2 2 B
3 3 A
4 4 B
> sapply(AB, class)
        A         B 
"integer"  "factor" 
> str(AB)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ A: int  1 2 3 4
 $ B: Factor w/ 2 levels "A","B": 1 2 1 2
```

Answer (score 3):

You should bare in mind, though, that `cbind` will return an atomic vector (matrix) when applied solely on atomic vectors (`double` in this case). As you can see in @prasad's and @Aaron's answers, resulting object is a matrix. If you specify other atomic vectors (integer, double, logical, complex) along with character vector, they will get coerced to character. And then you have a problem - you have to convert them to desired classes. So,

> if A, B, C & D are all vectors of
>   equal length, one can create
>   data.frame ABCD with

```
ABCD <- data.frame(A, B, C, D)
```

Perhaps you should ask *"how can I easily gather various vectors of equal length and put them in a `data.frame`"?* `cbind` is great, but sometimes it's not what you're looking for...

Comment: One solution would be to use cbind.data.fram(): do.call(cbind.data.frame, list). See this thread: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/R-why-it-returns-list-level-number-instead-of-its-content-td810803.html

Answer (score 1):

You can put all vectors in environment into list using eapply.

```
obj.list <- eapply(.GlobalEnv,function(x) if(is.vector(x)) x)
obj.list <- obj.list[names(obj.list) %in% LETTERS]
```