# Using some sort of bind() function to create a data.frame with coefficients from nested models?

Tags: r

I think I'm on to a good idea, but don't know how to implement it.  I am currently running a number of nested models.  For example:

```
y<-c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)
x1<-c(1, 0, 9, 9, 1, 9, 2, 1, 0)
x2<-c(1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 2, 4, 5, 1)
x3<-c(1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 4, 8, 3)

model1 <-lm(y~x1)
model2 <-lm(y~x1+x2)
model3 <-lm(y~x1+x2+x3)

model1_output<-(summary(model1 )$coefficients[1])
model2_output<-(summary(model1 )$coefficients[1])
model3_output<-(summary(model1 )$coefficients[1])
```

I would then like to put all of my output in a data table that matches along the rows (variable names) but inserts the new coefficients in their own columns. I'd like the data.frame presenting the output from my example as:

```
             b(Model 1)  b(Model 2) b(Model 3)
 (Intercept)  0.59217    0.2555     0.27983
 x1           0.05220    0.04116    0.0375
 x2              NA      0.12530    0.15142
 x3              NA      NA        -0.02994
```

I'm sure there must be some smart way to do this using the plyr() package (or some other package!), but can't seem to figure it out.  Thanks!

Comment: This answer is very relevant and likely more flexible than some of what has been discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962576/how-can-i-rbind-vectors-matching-their-column-names

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962267/cbind-a-df-with-an-empty-df-cbind-fill) from another question:

```
cbind.fill<-function(...){
    nm <- list(...) 
    nm<-lapply(nm, as.matrix)
    n <- max(sapply(nm, nrow)) 
    do.call(cbind, lapply(nm, function (x) 
    rbind(x, matrix(, n-nrow(x), ncol(x))))) 
}
```

You could do this:

```
do.call(cbind.fill,lapply(list(model1,model2,model3),function(x){coef(x)}))

                  [,1]       [,2]        [,3]
(Intercept) 0.59216966 0.25551154  0.27982881
x1          0.05220228 0.04116431  0.03754457
                    NA 0.12530141  0.15142340
                    NA         NA -0.02993768
```

And then set the row and column names manually. (Note that this returns a matrix, not a data frame, if that matters to you.)

Comment: Quick question--How would I add multiple columns relating to my coefficients?  I tried: `do.call(cbind.fill,lapply(list(model1,model2,model3),function(x){coef[1:4](x)}))` but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. I tried to keep it as general as possible, and borrowed some help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542542/using-cbind-on-an-arbitrarily-long-list-of-objects).

```
models <- list(model1=model1,model2=model2,model3=model3)    

#Find out which model (by index) has the most coefficients.
max.model <- which.max(unlist(lapply(models, function(x) length(x[[1]]))))

#How many coefficients there are in the 'biggest' model (including intercept)
max <- length(models[[max.model]][[1]])

#Create list of coefficients, replacing blank spaces with NA
coeff <- lapply(models, function(x) c(x[[1]],rep(NA,max-length(x[[1]]))))

#See the link above
result <- do.call(cbind,coeff)

colnames(result) <- names(models)

rownames(result) <- names(models[[max.model]][[1]])
```

Result:

```
> result
                model1     model2      model3
(Intercept) 0.59216966 0.25551154  0.27982881
x1          0.05220228 0.04116431  0.03754457
x2                  NA 0.12530141  0.15142340
x3                  NA         NA -0.02993768
```

What I mean by trying to keep it general is that this would work with any number of models; only the first line of code needs to change.