# How to rbind two matrix with different number of columns?

Tags: r, matrix, rbind

How to rbind two matrix with different row numbers
I have two matrix with different number of row, when I tried to combine them, there is error report:

```
A <- matrix (1:4, 2)
B <- matrix (6:11, 2)
rbind(A,B)
```

> ```
> "Error in rbind(A, B):
>   number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)"
> ```

I want

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    3
 [2,]    2    4
 [1,]    6    8   10
 [2,]    7    9   11
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962576/how-can-i-rbind-vectors-matching-their-column-names

Answer (score 2):

We can  convert to `data.frame` and use `bind_rows`.  If the column names are not matching, it will fill `NA` by default

```
library(dplyr)
out <- bind_rows(as.data.frame(A),  as.data.frame(B))
as.matrix(out)
```

Answer (score 2):

*We can use `plyr` package:*

```
plyr::rbind.fill.matrix(A, B)

 #>      1 2  3
 #> [1,] 1 3 NA
 #> [2,] 2 4 NA
 #> [3,] 6 8 10
 #> [4,] 7 9 11
```