# R - cbind lists ( lm summary )

Tags: r, list, cbind

I am looking to `cbind` `lm summary` stored in different lists. 
I have like 20 different models stored, so I would like to avoir `cbind` by hand.

Do you have any idea how I could do this  ?

Here are a sample of my `list`

```
data = list(structure(list(`a alone` = structure(c(4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L
), .Names = c("(Intercept)", "isexMALE", "numchild_rec1", "numchild_rec2", 
"numchild_rec>2"), .Label = c("-59.819", "-61.193", "-72.312", 
"126.679", "9.825"), class = "factor"), pvalue = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Names = c("(Intercept)", "isexMALE", "numchild_rec1", 
"numchild_rec2", "numchild_rec>2"), .Label = c(" ", "***"), class =         "factor")), .Names = c("a alone", 
"pvalue"), row.names = c("(Intercept)", "isexMALE", "numchild_rec1", 
"numchild_rec2", "numchild_rec>2"), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
    `b partner` = structure(c(4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Names = c("(Intercept)", 
"isexMALE", "numchild_rec1", "numchild_rec2", "numchild_rec>2"
), .Label = c("-222.064", "-259.233", "-277.213", "365.149", 
"8.608"), class = "factor"), pvalue = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Names = c("(Intercept)", "isexMALE", "numchild_rec1", 
"numchild_rec2", "numchild_rec>2"), .Label = c(" ", "***"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("b partner", "pvalue"), row.names = c("(Intercept)", 
"isexMALE", "numchild_rec1", "numchild_rec2", "numchild_rec>2"
), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(`c child` = structure(c(4L, 
1L, 5L, 2L, 3L), .Names = c("(Intercept)", "isexMALE", "numchild_rec1", 
"numchild_rec2", "numchild_rec>2"), .Label = c("-36.267", "112.03", 
"119.228", "23.706", "86.989"), class = "factor"), pvalue = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Names = c("(Intercept)", "isexMALE", "numchild_rec1", 
"numchild_rec2", "numchild_rec>2"), .Label = c("**", "***"), class =     "factor")), .Names = c("c child", 
"pvalue"), row.names = c("(Intercept)", "isexMALE", "numchild_rec1", 
 "numchild_rec2", "numchild_rec>2"), class = "data.frame"))
```

I would like to get an output like this

```
               a alone pvalue b partner pvalue c child pvalue
(Intercept)    126.679    ***   365.149    ***  23.706     **
isexMALE         9.825            8.608        -36.267    ***
numchild_rec1  -59.819    ***  -222.064    ***  86.989    ***
numchild_rec2  -61.193    ***  -259.233    ***  112.03    ***
numchild_rec>2 -72.312    ***  -277.213    *** 119.228    ***
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
 data<- as.data.frame(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use `cbind`, you could do:

```
data <- do.call(cbind, data)
```

There is a subtle difference in the output between this solution and the accepted answer, and that is that `cbind` will preserve the variable names, whereas `data.frame` will change them (to avoid duplicated column names and also eliminate spaces). So:

```
data_cb <- do.call(cbind, data)
data_df <- data.frame(data)

names(data_cb)
[1] "a alone"   "pvalue"    "b partner" "pvalue"    "c child"   "pvalue" 

names(data_df)
[1] "a.alone"   "pvalue"    "b.partner" "pvalue.1"  "c.child"   "pvalue.2"
```

This illustrates the fact that `cbind` might not always produce the output in the desired format. See more discussion on this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542542/using-cbind-on-an-arbitrarily-long-list-of-objects/5543168#5543168) and link in the respective comment.